Cursor from Magic Mouse 2 suddenly doesn't move horizontally
I didn't really do anything on my MacBook Pro (M1), besides implementing my work Mail account with the Mail app yesterday. However, everything still worked fine yesterday. But today somehow the cursor of my Magic Mouse 2 can only move vertically and can only barely move horizontally. I tried a few things to fix it:

turn the mouse off/on
reconnect
restart the MacBook
delete the files
reset bluetooth using sudo pkill bluetoothd in the terminal
delete the PLiST 3 files for the mouse in the library, as recommended here and then restart the Mac

As I also have BetterTouchTool, I thought that there might be some problems related to it, so I turned it off. But the problem persists. Connecting the mouse to a different Mac made me realize that my mouse is perfectly fine. There's some problems with my Mac. What should I do?

Please take two standard diagnostic steps: (1) Boot in Safe Mode and test, and (2) enable the Guest User in the Users & Groups settings, log in as Guest, and test.

@LincDavis I just tested it. Unfortunately, the problem occurred in both Safe Mode and as a Guest User.

Do you use any other Bluetooth devices with this Mac, and if so, are they working normally?

Does the cursor move correctly when using the laptop touchpad?

@LincDavis I'm also using a Magic Keyboard and Bluetooth Headphones. They're working fine.

@SteveM Yes, there are no issues with the touchpad.

Although it's a nuisance, I think what I would do at this point is boot in Restore mode and test. If you get the same results there, you will have ruled out everything except a hardware fault of some kind -- and yes, I know the mouse is working with another Mac. I can't explain that.

I meant Recovery mode.

@LincDavis Just did that. Unfortunately, the bug still appears there. I think I'll try contacting Apple Support or maybe wait until there's a macOS update. Some problems do disappear after an update.
